# Pointer to another class as a property

Tags: c++, pointers, properties

Why I receive an error when I try to create a property to another class through a pointer like that:

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

#include <string>
//using namespace std;

    #include "Player.h"

class Square

{
public:

    Square(int); 
    void process();

protected:

    int ID;
    Player* PlayerOn;          <---

};



    #endif
```

and the Player class is :

```
    #ifndef PLAYER_H
    #define PLAYER_H

    #include <string>
//using namespace std;

    #include "Square.h"

class Player
{
public:

    Player(int,int);
//  ~Player(void);
    int playDice();


private:

        int ID;
        int money;


};
#endif
```

I receive:

```
syntax error missing ; before * (on the declaration of  Player* PlayerOn;)
```

and missing type specifier (on the same line...)

Comment: Your post hurts my eyes, could you put the code for each file into code blocks, instead of splitting them up into several?

Comment: Why have you included Square.h in Player.h?

Comment: @Mark that's the cause of his error (due to the `#ifdef`s), you might want to put that in an answer :)

Comment: Damn, I can't answer now. I don't want to steal any upvotes from Mark haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are inclding Square.h in Player.h and so when you get `Player* PlayerOn;` Player is not defined

Either do not have the  `#include "Square.h"` in your Player.h which will work with this code. If the actual code is more complex replace the `#include "Square.h"` with a forward declaration of Square `class Square;`

Comment: Ok, you are correct, but I think in Java the superfluous imports do not cause a problem, do they?

Comment: Java and C++ are different languages so it does not matter what Java does for this question. - there are several reasons why java imports don't behave in this way

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a problem of recursive includes. You should use forward declaration in your square class.

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

#include <string>
//using namespace std;

class Player; //You will have to use the #include "player.h" in your .cpp

class Square

{
public:

    Square(int); 
    void process();

protected:

    int ID;
    Player* PlayerOn;          <---

};
```